# How to visualize focus in Swing control?

Tags: java, swing, focus, custom-controls

I have some Swing control, that does not show if it has a focus (actually, this is [`PCanvas`](http://www.piccolo2d.org/doc/piccolo2d.java/release-1.3/core/apidocs/edu/umd/cs/piccolo/PCanvas.html), but probably this does not matter).

Now I want to make this control showing if it is focused.

I expect two options:

1) Any control in Swing is capable to show focus, but this feature is OFF by default. Then how to turn it ON?

2) Control does not display focus by default, then how to do that? I can override `paintBorder`, but should I do something else?

Comment: a) no there is no default behaviour, it depends on the concrete ui-delegate b) don't override paintBorder - instead use a focusListener and set the border depending on focus state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose you can use [`FocusListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) for example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    public Example() {
        JButton button = new JButton("btn");
        add(button,BorderLayout.WEST);
        JTextField field = new JTextField(5);
        field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                ((JTextField)arg0.getComponent()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                ((JTextField)arg0.getComponent()).setBorder(null);
            }
        });

        add(field,BorderLayout.EAST);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }
}
```

[image]